Need advice on how to sister cut joist
I'm installing a range hood, and need to make room for the Ducting. Unfortunately the hole is going right through a ceiling joist (will use bends to avoid cutting the rafter).
I understand it's fine to cut ceiling joists with proper sistering, however in my case there flat boards above the adjacent wall void that I'm unsure about. Do I cut through them as well? I was planning on doing double headers on either end of the cut joist running to the two adjacent joists, but with those boards there, the headers would have to sit on top of them, which would mean i'd only be able to use 2x4s instead of 2x6s. Is that acceptable? Anyone know the function of the flat boards? Any advice on how to approach this would be great.


Can you provide pics and/or details on the range hood?  It would be better to avoid cutting the joist; additional detail may help us figure a way to do that.

The horizontal boards parallel to the joists may be related to a wall below. They serve as lateral support and backing for the ceiling drywall. Judging by the wires coming out, this is the case. It's usually not a problem to cut sections of these boards out as needed, which may resolve the primary issue with your original plan.
The one running crosswise is a "rat run"--a brace to hold joist position for temporary or permanent structural reasons and which provides support and anchorage for diagonal braces usually present at gable walls.
You have a few options if you'd rather not cut out the wall backing. All you're really trying to do is keep the drywall from sagging, so it's not a hypercritical thing.
Best
Lay headers across two or four adjacent joists and use strap hangers on the cut joist segments. These are essentially just joist hangers with extended legs to reach up higher.
Not too bad
Just lay lower-profile headers (flat 2x8 or 4x4) across two or four adjacent joists and run a pair of 3/8" lag screws into each ceiling joist stub from the top. Properly piloted, and with penetration of at least 2", these will hold just fine.
A-OK
Go with your original plan, but lift the headers over the flat boards (1½"). You won't have as much vertical distance to mount to at the ends of the headers, but they'll be just as strong otherwise. You could even notch the ends of the headers over the adjacent joists for bearing.
